# Make more @path in Retrofit URL

Tags: android, retrofit

I need help on how to use more than one parameter '@path' in retrofit request. I tried using single parameter '@Path' this way it worked.

```
@GET("topics/{id}?userId=58bf87d343c3ccb5793b2e99")
Call<ResponseBody> artikel(@Path("id") String id);
```

but I want to use two parameters like this

ApiService.class :

```
@GET("topics/{id}?userId={userId}")
Call<ResponseBody> artikelFeeds(@Path("id") String id, @Path("userId") String userId);
```

which throws error 'path must not have replace block'
and this is the part of retrofit client

```
Call<ResponseBody> get_artikel;
    Retrofit retrofit;
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Status.HOST_ARTICLE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();

    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    get_artikel = apiService.artikelFeeds(id,userId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
@GET("topics/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> artikelFeeds(@Path("id") String id, @Query("userId") String userId);
```

Comment: how about in proccess code ?

`ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    get_artikel = apiService.artikelFeeds(id,userId);`

Comment: use the same. no change

Comment: `500` is the server error. try this inside the `onResponse` method of your retrofit call for the log. `try {
                    System.out.println(response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Answer (score 0):

You make a query after `?` sign, so you need to annotate with `@Query`

```
@GET("topics/{id}Call<ResponseBody> artikelFeeds(@Path("id") String id, @Query("userId") String userId);
```

Comment: how about in here sir? like this : `get_artikel = apiService.artikelFeeds(id,userId);` , i got error code 500

Comment: `500` error code is from server, you don't do something wrong, unless you send bad informations and mess the server querry.